# PHP calculation result not showing correct currency format

Tags: php

In the following code I am trying to get the results:

```
$time_base_cost_day;
```

and

```
$time_base_cost_month;
```

to show with correct currency comma separators like `$1,456.00` or `$100,456.00`

I have tried a couple of examples but not sure where I am not adding the function correctly.

Thank you for your help

```
<?php 
  $choose_industry = $_POST['choose_industry'];
  $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
  $hourly_rate = $_POST['hourly_rate'];
  $billable_rate = $_POST['billable_rate'];
 $working_days = $_POST['working_days'];
 $wasted_time_per_day = $_POST['wasted_time_per_day'];
  $no_of_trucks = $_POST['no_of_trucks'];
 $fuel_price_per_liter = $_POST['fuel_price_per_liter'];
 $fuel_wasted_per_hr = $_POST['fuel_wasted_per_hr'];

 $time_base_cost_day = $hourly_rate*$wasted_time_per_day;
  $time_base_cost_month = $time_base_cost_day*$working_days;

 $productivity_costs_day = $billable_rate*$wasted_time_per_day;
  $productivity_costs_month = $productivity_costs_day*$working_days;

 $fuel_base_cost_day = $wasted_time_per_day*$fuel_price_per_liter*$fuel_wasted_per_hr;
 $fuel_base_cost_month = $fuel_base_cost_day*$working_days;
  $monthly_cost_per_unit = 35;
  $lost_per_vehicle_per_month = ($time_base_cost_month+$productivity_costs_month+$fuel_base_cost_month) - $monthly_cost_per_unit ;

 $monthly_savings_per_truck = $lost_per_vehicle_per_month;//Monthly Savings = (Monthly Time Based Costs + Monthly Productivity Costs + Monthly Fuel Based Costs) – Monthly Costs per Unit.

 $monthly_savings_per_fleet = $monthly_savings_per_truck*$no_of_trucks;


   $monthly_cost_per_fleet = $no_of_trucks*$monthly_cost_per_unit;



    $link = mysql_connect('##', '##', '##');
    mysql_select_db('##', $link);


 if( (!empty($choose_industry)) && (!empty($company_name)) && (!empty($hourly_rate)) && (!empty($billable_rate)) && (!empty($working_days)) && (!empty($wasted_time_per_day)) && (!empty($no_of_trucks)) && (!empty($fuel_price_per_liter)) && (!empty($fuel_wasted_per_hr)) && (!empty($time_base_cost_day)) && (!empty($time_base_cost_month)) && (!empty($productivity_costs_day)) && (!empty($productivity_costs_month)) && (!empty($fuel_base_cost_day)) && (!empty($fuel_base_cost_month)) && (!empty($monthly_savings_per_truck)) && (!empty($monthly_savings_per_fleet)) ){

 $result = mysql_query("INSERT into wp_calculate (id, choose_industry, company_name, hourly_rate, billable_rate, working_days, wasted_time_per_day, no_of_trucks, fuel_price_per_liter, fuel_wasted_per_hr, time_base_cost_day, time_base_cost_month, productivity_costs_day, productivity_costs_month, fuel_base_cost_day, fuel_base_cost_month, monthly_savings_per_truck, monthly_savings_per_fleet, monthly_cost_per_unit, monthly_cost_per_fleet, Date ) values ('', '$choose_industry','$company_name', '$hourly_rate', '$billable_rate', '$working_days', '$wasted_time_per_day', '$no_of_trucks', '$fuel_price_per_liter', '$fuel_wasted_per_hr', '$time_base_cost_day', '$time_base_cost_month', '$productivity_costs_day', '$productivity_costs_month', '$fuel_base_cost_day', '$fuel_base_cost_month', '$monthly_savings_per_truck', '$monthly_savings_per_fleet', '$monthly_cost_per_unit', '$monthly_cost_per_fleet', now() )");
 $last_id = mysql_insert_id();

 $sql = "UPDATE wp_calculate SET pdf_link='/main/downloadpdf.php?user_id=$last_id' WHERE id=$last_id";
 $retval = mysql_query($sql);

?>


 <div class="offset-wrapper push-down3" id="cost_based">
<!--<div class="span6"></div>
<div class="span6"></div>-->
<div class="row cost_row" id="cost_row">
   <div class="custom-calc-inner-2 wow bounceInLeft" data-wow-duration="3s" data-wow-delay="1s">
        <h4>Time Based Costs</h4>
        <p>Cost of wasted time (per driver)</p>
    <div class="result">        
        <div class="pos-left">
        <p class="value">DAY</p><p class="lbl">$<?php echo $time_base_cost_day; ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="pos-right">
        <p class="lbl">$<?php echo $time_base_cost_month; ?></p><p class="value">MONTH</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: use php function number_format()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo number_format($time_base_cost_day,2);

echo number_format($time_base_cost_month,2);
```

`2` is for how many decimals, and you still can add comma or dot, like:

- The default pattern is as you want (comma-separated thousands and dot for decimals, so you doesn't NEED to use this part below)

  echo number_format($time_base_cost_month,2,',','.'); //returns 1.456,00

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Another thing that will save your time in the future: don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, try to use *PDO* or at least *mysqli* ;)

Comment: thank you Dimas, a developer was working in this page, I am just starting to get familiar with php. I just added what you suggested but its not working I added it like this <?php 
echo number_format($time_base_cost_day,2);

echo number_format($time_base_cost_month,2);
?> Am I missing something or am I adding it in the wrong place?

Comment: It throws any errors? Yes, the syntax is correct, you're pasting it into a *.php* file, right?

Comment: I copied and pasted your two lines here  $sql = "UPDATE wp_calculate SET pdf_link='/main/downloadpdf.php?user_id=$last_id' WHERE id=$last_id";
 $retval = mysql_query($sql);

?>  between the $retval= and ?> yes it is in a php file, no error but it is throwing some large calculated number somewhere random in the page, the code is not getting appied on the time base cost day or time base cost month those remain unaffected

Comment: Ok, paste it after *($sql);*... `$retval = mysql_query($sql); echo number_format($time_base_cost_day,2)."\n"; echo number_format($time_base_cost_month,2); ?>`

Comment: FYI, *$retval* is a variable, which records the value of what comes next (in this case, *mysql_query...*) to be used later.

Comment: worked like a charm I just had to add it to the correct place in the html code that was all, will this show correctly in the same format with just thousands or will add the same correct commas for hunders of thousands and millions etc?

Comment: Great! And yes, it will add the commas to every group of thousands.

Comment: after this form gives the results of the calculations the user can create a pdf. I added the code to the front end like this which did exactly as you described:  <p class="value">DAY</p><p class="lbl">$<?php echo number_format($time_base_cost_day,2)."\n"; ?></p>                                      but when I add it to the pdf php code Im not sure where I am messing with the syntax:  <td class="cost_tb">$'number_format(.$productivity_costs_day,2)."\n"'</td>

Comment: The syntax is wrong, try this: `<td class="cost_tb">$'.number_format($productivity_costs_day,2)."\n"'</td>`. Also, take a look in this tutorial by W3Schools, might help you quickier than me: http://www.w3schools.com/php/ :)